# Material UI React Table Pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to inquire about Table Pagination in React UI Material.

Here I am trying to implement all the data from the API.

Some of the data that I have successfully implemented is from the API to the Material UI Table.

1. Bring up data based on request Rows Per Page
2. Bring up the data comes from the API that I have.

However when I try to implement Pagination, the Data doesn't appear properly from the API.

Example:
When the Component is rendered for the first time, it will display 5 data from the API. But when I tried to move to the next page, only the response from the API was successful, but not the data that appeared.

Here I divide it into several files:

1. Index Component
2. Index Container

File Index Component.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

// * Material UI
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogContent,
  DialogContentText,
  DialogActions,
  Grid,
  TableContainer,
  Table,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  TableCell,
  TableBody,
  TablePagination,
  CssBaseline
} from '@material-ui/core'

import {
  Add
} from '@material-ui/icons'

// * Core Component
import Layout from '@containers/v2/core/Layout'
import InputCategoryComponent from './Input'
import CardCore from '../../core/shared/Card'
import Controls from '../../core/shared/controls'
import { isEmpty } from '@client/libs/utils'

const columns = [
  { id: 'name', label: 'Name', minWidth: 500 },
  { id: 'Actions', label: 'Action', minWidth: 100 }
]

export default function CategoryComponent ({
  page = 0,
  rowsPerPage = 5,
  rowsPerPageOptions = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25],
  startDate = '',
  endDate = '',
  sortBy = 'created_at',
  sortDirection = 'desc',
  search = '',
  totalCount = 0,
  items = [],
  fetch = () => {},
  createPaymentCategory = () => {},
  readPaymentCategory = () => {},
  updatePaymentCategory = () => {},
  deletePaymentCategory = () => {},
  handleRowPerPage = () => {},
  handlePagination = () => {}
}) {
  const [isTable, setTable] = useState(true)
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState(false)
  const [hashed, setHashed] = useState('')

  const [initialModel, setModel] = useState([])
  const emptyRows = rowsPerPage - Math.min(rowsPerPage, totalCount - page * rowsPerPage)

  const handleTable = (params) => {
    setTable(params)
  }

  const handleAlertOpen = (payload) => {
    setHashed(payload)
    setAlert(true)
  }

  const handleChange = (payload) => {
    if (isEmpty(payload)) {
      setModel({
        name: ''
      })
      setTable(false)
    } else {
      readPaymentCategory(payload).then((res) => {
        setModel(res.data)
        setTable(false)
      })
    }
  }

  const handleAlertClose = () => {
    setAlert(false)
  }

  const onFinish = () => {
    fetch(
      page,
      rowsPerPage,
      startDate,
      endDate,
      sortBy,
      sortDirection,
      search
    )
    setTable(true)
    setModel({
      name: ''
    })
  }

  const onDelete = () => {
    deletePaymentCategory(hashed).then(() => {
      setHashed('')
      setAlert(false)
      fetch(
        page,
        rowsPerPage,
        startDate,
        endDate,
        sortBy,
        sortDirection,
        search
      )
    })
  }

  const onRowChange = (e) => {
    handleRowPerPage(e.target.value)
    fetch(
      0,
      e.target.value,
      startDate,
      endDate,
      sortBy,
      sortDirection,
      search
    )
  }

  const onPageChange = (event, newPage) => {
    handlePagination(newPage)
    fetch(
      newPage,
      rowsPerPage,
      startDate,
      endDate,
      sortBy,
      sortDirection,
      search
    )
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <CssBaseline />
      {isTable && (
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item sm={12} md={12} lg={12}>
            <CardCore
              variant='info'
              title='Payment Category'
            >
              <Grid container>
                <Grid item sm={12} md={12} lg={!2}>
                  <Controls.Button
                    text='Create'
                    color='primary'
                    startIcon={<Add />}
                    onClick={() => handleChange()}
                  />
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
              <Grid container>
                <Grid item sm={12} md={12} lg={!2}>
                  <TableContainer>
                    <Table stickyHeader aria-label='sticky table'>
                      <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                          {columns.map((column) => (
                            <TableCell
                              key={column.id}
                              align={column.align}
                              style={{ minWidth: column.minWidth }}
                            >
                              {column.label}
                            </TableCell>
                          ))}
                        </TableRow>
                      </TableHead>
                      <TableBody>
                        {items.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage).map((row) => {
                          return (
                            <TableRow hover role='checkbox' tabIndex={-1} key={row.name}>
                              <TableCell>{row.name}</TableCell>
                              <TableCell align='left'>
                                <div>
                                  <Controls.Button
                                    text='Edit'
                                    color='inherit'
                                    onClick={() => handleChange(row.hashed_id)}
                                  />
                                  <Controls.Button
                                    text='Delete'
                                    color='secondary'
                                    onClick={() => handleAlertOpen(row.hashed_id)}
                                  />
                                </div>
                              </TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                          )
                        })}

                        {emptyRows > 0 && (
                          <TableRow style={{ height: 53 * emptyRows }}>
                            <TableCell colSpan={6} />
                          </TableRow>
                        )}
                      </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                  </TableContainer>
                  <TablePagination
                    rowsPerPageOptions={rowsPerPageOptions}
                    component='div'
                    count={totalCount}
                    rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
                    page={page}
                    onChangePage={onPageChange}
                    onChangeRowsPerPage={onRowChange}
                  />
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </CardCore>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      )}
      <Dialog
        open={alert}
        onClose={handleAlertClose}
        fullWidth
        maxWidth='sm'
        aria-labelledby='alert-dialog-title'
        aria-describedby='alert-dialog-description'
      >
        <DialogTitle id='alert-dialog-title'>Are you sure want to delete this?</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id='alert-dialog-description'>
            You wont be able to revert this!
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Controls.Button
            text='Disagree'
            color='secondary'
            onClick={handleAlertClose}
          />
          <Controls.Button
            text='Agree'
            color='primary'
            autoFocus
            onClick={onDelete}
          />
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
      {!isTable && (
        <InputCategoryComponent
          controlTable={handleTable}
          initialValues={initialModel}
          callBack={onFinish}
          createData={createPaymentCategory}
          updateData={updatePaymentCategory}
        />
      )}
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

File Index Container.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { mapStateToProps, mapActions } from '@client/store'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

// * Category Component
import CategoryComponent from '@components/v2/Payment/Category/Index'

class PaymentCategoryContainer extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      page: 0,
      rowsPerPage: 5,
      rowsPerPageOptions: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25],
      startDate: '',
      endDate: '',
      sortBy: 'created_at',
      sortDirection: 'desc',
      search: '',
      totalCount: 0,
      items: []
    }
    this.fetch = this.fetch.bind(this)
    this.handleRow = this.handleRow.bind(this)
    this.handlePage = this.handlePage.bind(this)
  }

  fetch (page, rowsPerPage, startDate, endDate, sortBy, sortDirection, search) {
    this.props.fetchPaymentCategory(
      page,
      rowsPerPage,
      startDate,
      endDate,
      sortBy,
      sortDirection,
      search
    ).then((res) => {
      if (res?.status === 200) {
        this.setState({
          items: res?.data.items,
          totalCount: res?.data.totalItems
        })
      } else {
        console.log('error')
      }
    })
  }

  handleRow (rowsPerPage) {
    this.setState({
      rowsPerPage: rowsPerPage
    })
    const { page, startDate, endDate, sortBy, sortDirection, search } = this.state
    this.fetch(
      page,
      rowsPerPage,
      startDate,
      endDate,
      sortBy,
      sortDirection,
      search
    )
  }

  handlePage (numberOfPage) {
    this.setState({
      page: numberOfPage
    })
    const { rowsPerPage, startDate, endDate, sortBy, sortDirection, search } = this.state
    this.fetch(
      numberOfPage,
      rowsPerPage,
      startDate,
      endDate,
      sortBy,
      sortDirection,
      search
    )
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.fetch(
      this.state.page,
      this.state.rowsPerPage,
      '',
      '',
      this.state.sortBy,
      this.state.sortDirection,
      ''
    )
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <CategoryComponent
        {...this.props}
        {...this.state}
        fetch={this.fetch}
        handleRowPerPage={this.handleRow}
        handlePagination={this.handlePage}
      />
    )
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps('paymentCategory'),
  mapActions(
    'fetchPaymentCategory',
    'changeRowPerPage',
    'changePagination',
    'createPaymentCategory',
    'readPaymentCategory',
    'updatePaymentCategory',
    'deletePaymentCategory'
  )
)(PaymentCategoryContainer)
```

Response data from API:

```
items: [] => array. totalItems: 0 => int
```

Are there any mistakes that I missed? or is there a step that i missed ?.

I am following the examples in [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/components/tables/EnhancedTable.js) section ui material.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found where the mistake I made. I shouldn't need to `slice()` the data. Because I have a params page query so I just need to `map()` something like this.

```js
return (
    <Layout>
      <CssBaseline />
      {isTable && (
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item sm={12} md={12} lg={12}>
            <CardCore
              variant='info'
              title='Payment Category'
            >
              <Grid container>
                <Grid item sm={12} md={12} lg={!2}>
                  <Controls.Button
                    text='Create'
                    color='primary'
                    startIcon={<Add />}
                    onClick={() => handleChange()}
                  />
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
              <Grid container>
                <Grid item sm={12} md={12} lg={!2}>
                  <TableContainer>
                    <Table stickyHeader aria-label='sticky table'>
                      <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                          {columns.map((column) => (
                            <TableCell
                              key={column.id}
                              align={column.align}
                              style={{ minWidth: column.minWidth }}
                            >
                              {column.label}
                            </TableCell>
                          ))}
                        </TableRow>
                      </TableHead>
                      <TableBody>
                        {items.map((row) => {
                          return (
                            <TableRow hover role='checkbox' tabIndex={-1} key={row.name}>
                              <TableCell>{row.name}</TableCell>
                              <TableCell align='left'>
                                <div>
                                  <Controls.Button
                                    text='Edit'
                                    color='inherit'
                                    onClick={() => handleChange(row.hashed_id)}
                                  />
                                  <Controls.Button
                                    text='Delete'
                                    color='secondary'
                                    onClick={() => handleAlertOpen(row.hashed_id)}
                                  />
                                </div>
                              </TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                          )
                        })}

                        {emptyRows > 0 && (
                          <TableRow style={{ height: 53 * emptyRows }}>
                            <TableCell colSpan={6} />
                          </TableRow>
                        )}
                      </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                  </TableContainer>
                  <TablePagination
                    rowsPerPageOptions={rowsPerPageOptions}
                    component='div'
                    count={totalCount}
                    rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
                    page={page}
                    onChangePage={onPageChange}
                    onChangeRowsPerPage={onRowChange}
                  />
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </CardCore>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      )}
      <Dialog
        open={alert}
        onClose={handleAlertClose}
        fullWidth
        maxWidth='sm'
        aria-labelledby='alert-dialog-title'
        aria-describedby='alert-dialog-description'
      >
        <DialogTitle id='alert-dialog-title'>Are you sure want to delete this?</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id='alert-dialog-description'>
            You wont be able to revert this!
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Controls.Button
            text='Disagree'
            color='secondary'
            onClick={handleAlertClose}
          />
          <Controls.Button
            text='Agree'
            color='primary'
            autoFocus
            onClick={onDelete}
          />
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
      {!isTable && (
        <InputCategoryComponent
          controlTable={handleTable}
          initialValues={initialModel}
          callBack={onFinish}
          createData={createPaymentCategory}
          updateData={updatePaymentCategory}
        />
      )}
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Hope this helps others.